# Get slider value to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make an **imagecompression tool** in which I would like to define the compression rate with a slider.
The value of the slider is an input for the php-function imagejpeg and this is where I am stuck...

I can't get the slider value into php...

I am working with a **HTML** slider that I have created as followed:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1" id="compressSlider" name="ratiovalue"  oninput="ratioCalculate(value)" style="width:400px;">
    <span id="volume">100</span>
</form>
```

And this is my **Javascript** and **PHP**-code:

```
<script>        
        function ratioCalculate(slider) {
            var slideval = document.getElementById("volume");
            var filesizekb = document.getElementById("Filesizekb");
            var filesizepro = document.getElementById("Filesizepro");

            <?php

                $compressed_image = new handledImage();
                $temp_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_SESSION['targetfile']);

                if(isset($_POST['compressSlider'])) {  
                    imagejpeg($temp_image, 'uploads/compressedSliderImage.jpg', $_POST['compressSlider']);
                    $compressed_image->name = 'compressedSliderImage';
                    $compressed_image->type = 'jpg';
                    $compressed_image->size = filesize('uploads/compressedSliderImage.jpg');
                    $compressed_image->ratio = $_POST['compressSlider'];

                    $images[5] = $compressed_image;
               } 
               else {
                   $compressed_image->ratio = -1;
               }
            ?>

            slideval.innerHTML = slider;
            document.getElementById('compressed_shown').src = 'uploads/compressedSliderImage.jpg';
            filesizekb.innerHTML = 'Filesize (kB): '+<?php // echo convert_unit($images[5]->size); ?>;
            filesizepro.innerHTML = 'Filesize (%): '+<?php // echo calculate_percentage($images[5]->size, $images[0]->size); ?>;
        }

    </script>
```

Slider is the value of the slider in Javascript. The Javascript variable changes when I use my slider, but the php varaible ($_POST['compressSlider']) doesn't...

Comment: You could send the variable through AJAX to your php-script and have it return desired data back to your html-page.

Comment: You need to first of all go and understand that PHP runs on the server, and is done before the site even “arrives” in your browser. If you want to transfer any value from the client to the server, that of course requires a new HTTP request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the submit button?
You cannot update serverside synchronously with client side.
When do you reload the page and send the POST data?
I mean the data in the javascript function is set when loading the page.
Maybe an update button or apply? And reload the page using $_POST?

And the name is wrong..

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1" id="compressSlider" name="ratiovalue"  oninput="ratioCalculate(value)" style="width:400px;">
```

should be

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1" id="compressSlider" name="compressSlider"  oninput="ratioCalculate(value)" style="width:400px;">
```

Comment: Isn't everything updated when I use my slider by oninput? Because the decimal number next to my slider (slideval in JS) is changed. 

And if this is not the case? How can I make it so I don't have to click a Submit button?